# Errors in launching Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the following error while launching the **Android virtual device manager:**

```
> C:\Users\yates\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay
> none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_23_x86 <br/> init: Could not find
> wglGetExtensionsStringARB! <br/> emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does
> not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is
> ignored.<br/> getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x
> config!<br/> emulator: device fd:704<br/> Failed to obtain GLES 1.x
> extensions string!<br/> HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt
> mode<br/> Could not initialize emulated framebufferCannot set up guest
> memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument
```

Please **do not** tell me to

1. un-check 'GPU HOST': Already done that. It says it's about the screen resolution. And it keeps giving me the same error even when I change screen resolution.
2. install the HAXM: I have already done that.
3. to update my graphic drivers: I don't have any additional graphic cards in my system. 'STANDARD VGA GRAPHIC ADAPTER' is the only thing installed and it's up-to-date in my system.

Emulator Configuration:

> Name: Nexus_4_API_23
>
> CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
>
> Path: C:\Users\yates.android\avd\Nexus_4_API_23.avd
>
> Target: Google APIs (API level 23)
>
> Skin: nexus_4
>
> SD Card: C:\Users\yates.android\avd\Nexus_4_API_23.avd\sdcard.img
>
> Snapshot: no
>
> hw.dPad: no
>
> runtime.network.speed: full
>
> hw.accelerometer: yes
>
> hw.device.name: Nexus 4
>
> vm.heapSize: 64
>
> skin.dynamic: yes
>
> hw.device.manufacturer: Google
>
> hw.gps: yes
>
> hw.audioInput: yes
>
> tag.id: google_apis
>
> hw.camera.back: none
>
> hw.mainKeys: no
>
> AvdId: Nexus_4_API_23
>
> hw.camera.front: none
>
> hw.lcd.density: 320
>
> runtime.scalefactor: auto
>
> avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 4 API 23
>
> snapshot.present: no
>
> hw.device.hash2: MD5:6930e145748b87e87d3f40cabd140a41
>
> hw.ramSize: 864
>
> hw.trackBall: no
>
> hw.battery: yes
>
> hw.sdCard: yes
>
> tag.display: Google APIs
>
> runtime.network.latency: none
>
> hw.keyboard: yes
>
> hw.sensors.proximity: yes
>
> disk.dataPartition.size: 200M
>
> hw.sensors.orientation: yes
>
> avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
>
> hw.gpu.enabled: no

Comment: what is your system configuration...

Comment: intel i3 core 
6gb ram
32bit OS

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the RAM size of your emulator. Even if you have enought memory it is recommended to have 1GB or less than 1GB memory. As it automatically allocates 864MB edit your emulator in the AVD manager and reduce the AVD's RAM.

Open AVD Manager and select your device and click "Edit" button.

Then in "Memory Options" find the RAM parameter and set it to 512 or 864 for example. Click OK to save the current configuration and restart your application or AVD.

You also should not provide a RAM size for your emulator which exceeds your HAXM allocated memory. Since you are running the emulator in HAXM mode it will run faster than normal. So you don't have to worry about your devices' RAM.

Comment: Thanks ..! but now its giving me another error 

Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

Comment: Thanks a lot I just unchecked the option and it worked for me...! :) :) :)

Comment: @YatiSawhney for `Could not initialize emulated framebuffer` to it enough solution.

Comment: I am getting some some kind of disturbance in the emulater screen now.. :(

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio:

1. Open Avd manager
2. Edit the settings for the AVD configuration
3. Click in the "Show Advanced Settings"
4. In the "Memory and Storage" section reduce the RAM size

Comment: I am getting four frames in my new emulator now with a lot of disturbance also

Comment: what's your emulator configuration

Comment: Added that to the  question above

Comment: delete all the devices if u configured in AVD and choose Nexus one... it's working fine for me

Comment: why you not using your android cell phone as emulator...  check it  http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/tools/device.html

Comment: sorry, I din't face this kind of problem... but i think its a graphics problem so u update ur graphics driver.. first of all try nexus one it uses low resources of the system...